# Debug Exercise for Java 1

Tags: java, debugging

```
import java.util.*;  
import java.applet.*; 
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Game
{
public static void main(String[] args){  

System.out.println("I am ready to play!");
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What's your age?");
        String userinput = input.nextLine();
        if (userinput < 13){
            System.out.println("You are allowed to play at your own risk");
        } else
            System.out.println("Play On!");
        }
System.out.println("You are at an Iggy concert, and you hear this lyric 'Are you ready?, start       running.'");
System.out.println("Suddenly, Iggy stops and says, 'Who wants to race me at running?'");

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Do you want to race Iggy on stage?");
        String userinput = input.nextLine();
        if (userinput == yes){
            "You and Iggy start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!");
        } else
            System.out.println("Oh no! Iggy shakes his head and sings 'I set a pace, so I can race without pacing.'");

var feedback = prompt("Rate your game out of 10");
if(feedback > 8)
{
    console.log("Thank you! You should race again at the next concert!");
}
else
{
    console.log("I'll keep practicing coding and racing.");
}
}
}
```

This is an assignment for a Java 1 class in high school and I have no idea how to fix all of this.
I realize that there are a ton of errors and this is pretty irrelevant to anyone but me but I want to actually learn java and this class isn't teaching me anything, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Download an IDE like Netbeans/Eclipse/IntelliJ, start a project, add the code to it and follow the hints. That's the easiest way to learn.

Comment: When you compile it in any IDE it will tell you where the syntax errors are.  Start by cleaning up those.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly start reading on the java.util.Scanner & then read on String comparison ! 
I will not give you the answer but hints!

Some of the errors are :
1. You need to use .equals and not ==

```
String userinput = input.nextLine();
    if (userinput == yes)
```

2. you need an int not a string read on Interger.parseInt(String)

> String userinput = input.nextLine();
>         if (userinput < 13) {}

3. What is var and what is prompt ?

> var feedback = prompt("Rate your game out of 10");

4. console is not defines

> console.log("Thank you! You should race again at the next concert!");

5. this is defined twice.

> Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

& so on !!!

Comment: useless imports too.. this exercice is totally irrelevant